# Задачка по C++ про мишени

Tags: c++

Добрый день! Столкнулся с задачкой:

> Производится одиночный выстрел по мишени в виде круга, разделенного на пять колец, с шагом в 1 сантиметр. За попадание в «яблочко» начисляется 10 баллов, за попадание в каждое очередное кольцо соответственно 8, 6, 4, 2, 1 балл. За попадание в «молоко» - 0 баллов. Определить количество баллов, набранных после выстрела.

Так вот, я не особо понял что от меня хотят. Вообще бесит, что не могут нормально задачу описать, приходится додумываться самому. Я подумал так: по умолчанию задано уравнение 5 окружностей. Пользователь программы должен вводить координаты x,y куда он попал и ему выводиться баллы?  Если так то у меня вопросы:
 1. Правильно ли я задал уравнения x^2+y^2=0, следующее кольцо x^2+y^2=1 и т.д.?
 2. Проверку делать так: сначала проверить яблоко, потом второе кольцо и тд, если проверку ни одну не пройдёт, значит молоко, всё верно?
 3. Ну проверка делается, я полагаю, просто (x^2+y^2)==0, да?
**UPD:** Вот такой код получился

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int belongsToKolco(int r, int R, float R_user){
    if (R_user <= R && R_user >= r) return true;
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    int rat;
    float x,y,R;
        cout << "Vvedite koordinati tochki popadaniya:\nx=";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "y=";
        cin >> y;
        rat = 0;
        R = sqrt(x*x+y*y);
    if(R<=5){
        if((x*x+y*y)==0) rat = 10;
        if(belongsToKolco(0,1,R)) rat = 8;
        if(belongsToKolco(1,2,R)) rat = 6;
        if(belongsToKolco(2,3,R)) rat = 4;
        if(belongsToKolco(3,4,R)) rat = 2;
        if(belongsToKolco(4,5,R)) rat = 1;
    }
        cout << "Vashi balli: " << rat << "\n";
        return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так как-то?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x,y;
    cout<<"x = "; cin>>x; 
    cout<<"y = "; cin>>y;

    const int score[] = {10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1, 0};
    int r = ceil(sqrt(x*x+y*y));
    int index = (r < 6)?r:6;

    cout<<"score ="<<score[index]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но я уже сделал по своему, думаю, похоже, посмотри всё там верно логически пожалуйста? Апдейтом код поставил

Comment: При попадании в границу кольца баллы будут начислены по минимуму.
Так например, при попадании в яблочко начислит 8 баллов.
Надо что-то предпринять :)

Comment: яблоко это только одна точка (0;0) А вот в случаи с другим можно решить проблему с использованием else if. Спасибо!

Comment: Точка - это частный случай окружности. Может лучше "<":

    if (R_user < R && R_user >= r) return true;